# 1 times badge list typo

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

If you click to the drill down of any of the tag-badges which have been awarded precisely once (there are quite a few in [the gold category](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)) you see: "This badge has been awarded 1 times".

To pick [one at random](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1343/datetime):

[image: It just happens to be awarded to...]

Could we drop the 's', and change it to read "1 time"?

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: Well, since Jeff's no longer (heavily) involved, is this still true? I doubt he'll get out his bludgeoning-S for this. Maybe if you raised such a bug for Discourse.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: He did say *personally*...

Comment: @hayden: relax, that tweet is from 2009. I'm *pretty* sure you're not the "next person" ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer thank goodness for that! :)

Comment: Jeff can easily be distracted with a nice multi-monitor setup.

Comment: Am I the only one amazed by the datetime gold badge ?

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk: apart from being Jon Skeet, he's also *the* local Joda Time authority *and* the original author of noda-time. So if anyone has that badge, it has to be him. And, well, it is.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the giant S threat: we've fixed this as part of localization.

Comment: Nice, but why did you remove the "Recently awarded to"? I think it was proper to have in there, and helped to understand the order is by date awarded, descending.

Comment: and the full-stop!