# Plural one for awarded badge count: "Awarded 1 times"

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, plurals

Plurals live forever here. E.g. on [badge award page](/help/badges/292/ios-app):

> [image: 1 times]

Comment: Apparently this bug resurfaced: [1 times badge list typo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181533/295232)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["viewed 1 times"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times) or [alternatively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%221+times%22).

Comment: @Glorfindel as far as I know (according broken translations on ruSO) current text was improved (?) by adding a dot at the end, hence all translation were cleared, and pluralization for English version as well.

Comment: 1 is accused of being a 2 timer.

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if we could all just learn and speak Indonesian.

Comment: @Rob I fail to see how a recent, currently reproduceable bug report should be a duplicate of a 10 years old [tag:status-completed] report. **Voting to leave open**.

Comment: Totally agree with @MEE. New bug report can't be duplicate of a completed bug report. And we can't possibly wrap all the plural bugs into one single question.

Comment: It's a "won't fix, don't mention it", that's how it's a *dupe*.

Comment: One more reference to the case [Illuminator badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/328/ios-app)

> [image]